# unable to compare more than one character

Tags: c, char, scanf, getchar

I have written two programs. In the first one I'm not using getchar to take a character from keyboard, in this case, the compilation is completely missing the second scanf. So to overcome this I have used getchar. In this case I'm successfully able to give input but comparison is not happening. Though I have given input as "d" and "d" output is "bye" only.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
    char c,f;
    printf("e");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("one more");
    scanf("%c",&f);
    if(c=='d'&&f=='d')
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("bye");

}
```

with getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
 main(){
    char c,f;
    printf("e");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("one more");
    scanf("%c",&f);
    getchar();
    if(c=='d'&&f=='d')
        printf("hi");
    else
        printf("bye");

}
```

Comment: here i have given input as d and d , for this output has to be hi but it is giving as bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new line character will remain in standard input as it will not be consumed by the `scanf("%c")`. This means the second scanf() reads the newline charcacter, and not the next input. Changing to `scanf(" %c")` would be a solution, which will skip leading white space.

Comment: Better to skip the whitespace before the conversion. With a "%c\n" format, the `scanf` needs to find the next non-whitespace character before it returns.